# Flutter two finger swipe gesture recognizer

Tags: flutter

I'm working on swiping between different pages for my Flutter application. One of the screens is a full screen Google Map that uses all the single finger swipe gestures. I would like to keep these gestures, so I want to switch my PageView gestures to use two finger swipes instead.

Is there a supported way of doing this in Flutter?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [MultiDragGestureRecognizer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/MultiDragGestureRecognizer-class.html). You might want to build a custom gesture for your need. But another thing is that PageView gesture would also need to be changed with this custom gesture.

Comment: Thanks Gandev! How would I go about adding a custom gesture to PageView?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, tbh, you might need to test and check out with dragStartBehavior. I think its not possible directly based on my understanding which is limited at the moment. Please do revert back if you find anything.

Comment: The link didn't work, so i found it at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/MultiDragGestureRecognizer-class.html